# How to randomize a RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I'm trying to make a multiple choice quiz. I have a problem when I want to get a multiple choice button randomly. I wonder how to randomize the position of the multiple choice button. 
This is an example of my multiple choice button code.

```
       rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());
        rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
        rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());
```

I want to make randomize for example:

```
rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());
rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add question to array list and then shuffle it. Later take read it from index 0.

```
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add("Q1");
    arrayList.add("Q2");
    arrayList.add("Q3");
    Collections.shuffle(arrayList);

    // set array list items to radio buttons
```

Comment: what is q1 mean?

Comment: currentQuestion.getOption1() is Q1, like Question 1.